# PyCharm save console output to a file not working

Tags: pycharm

My program has a very long output (a lot of print) and I can't find a way to make PyCharm shows all output history, PyCharm only shows the few latest output in the run window. So instead I want to save the console output to a file so that I can see all output history

[image]

But it doesn't work? Where is the log file?

[image]

It says in the run window that PyCharm is saving the console output to a file, but where? I can't find it.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

After some tinkering with PyCharm, I found what seems likely to be a bug in PyCharm. PyCharm doesn't save console output to a file if the path points to a directory but not to a file

[image]

adding `\log.log` to the end of the path solves this issue:

[image]

I didn't create `log.log` file, PyCharm created the file when I run the program:

[image]